# Disable client validation through javascript

Tags: asp.net, validation, .net-4.0

I have a javascript method on my site that redirects the user after X minutes (just takes them to the log-in page because their session has expired).

I'm having an issue if there are any validation controls on the page, the validation could fail when the javascript method sets the window.location property to redirect the user.

Is there a way I can still redirect the user but stop the ASP.Net validation?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call:

```
ValidatorEnable("nameOfYourValidator", false);
```

for each control

---

Here's a complete list of ASP.Net Client Side Validation Information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside

> **ValidatorValidate(val)**
>
> Takes a client-validator as input. Makes the
> validator check its input and update its display.
>
> **ValidatorEnable(val, enable)**
>
> Takes a client-validator and a Boolean
> value. Enables or disables a client validator. Being disabled will
> stop it from evaluating and it will always appear valid.
>
> **ValidatorHookupControl(control, val)**
>
> Takes an input HTML element and a
> client-validator. Modifies or creates the element's change event so
> that it updates the validator when changed. This can be useful for
> custom validators that depend on multiple input values.

Comment: I probably should have included this, but I'm using .Net 4.0 and I used to have this method, but it's no longer available for some reason (just a bad call when I try that)